# What is the correct syntax for std::vector<std::unique_ptr<>>::push_back()?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdvector, unique-ptr

I have read that I need to define a deleter for a `unique_ptr` if I want to use `push_back` from `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`. Is that true? If yes what's the correct syntax to do that?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: 1. Have you tried to just push back unique pointers? 2. Have you considered [`std::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)?

Comment: It works exactly the same as for every other `push_back`. I have no idea why a custom deleter would be necessary. I suggest you post your code that fails. Then we can explain what is wrong.

Comment: Is that true? No. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/tVHB-5.

Comment: You can just do `vector.push_back(std::move(ptr))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need a custom deleter in the normal case. For an existing `unique_ptr`:

```
vector.push_back(std::move(ptr));
```

works fine (transferring ownership of the pointer to the `vector`); for a new pointer:

```
vector.push_back(std::make_unique<MyType>(args, go, here));
```

is the safest (since it ensures the pointer is always managed, even if `push_back` throws an exception), with:

```
vector.emplace_back(new MyType(args, go, here));
```

being perhaps a little faster, at the expense of potentially leaking memory if the `vector` raises an exception (e.g. due to a failed attempt to expand the underlying storage; though in that scenario, your program is likely doomed anyway, so it may not be worth defending against).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to write deleter if default one doesn't fit your need, so for specific resource.

Syntax to use `push_back` with movable non-copiable type is:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> vs;

vs.push_back(std::make_unique<T>(42));

std::unique_ptr<T> p = std::make_unique<T>(42);
vs.push_back(std::move(p));
```